# How to save a json file locally with dojo toolkit

Tags: javascript, android, json, eclipse, dojo

I'm trying to create a JSON file with dojo toolkit that need to be saved into local memory of the phone. The app need to be valid for android and IOS. I'm using ECLIPSE with ADT as a IDE. My principal issue is that normally the file created with dojo were saved as cache cause the web-oriented nature of dojo. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use dojo? You can use javascript and HTML5

Answer (score 1):

This is not very clear... If you use ADT how do you make compatible with IOS ? And what is dojo doing here ?

I guess you are using Phonegap for creating your app...
Maybe what you are looking for is:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html